# Facebook Open-graph Debugging Issue

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting an off error I've never seen from the Facebook OG debugger.

Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

URL I'm debugging: http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/

My Meta tags for FB/OG:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Dalliance Accessories" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Dalliance Accessories is proud to release our new collection with the launch of Dalliance 2.0! Drawing inspiration from all over the world, we are excited to present our new pieces featuring bold stones, neon chord, collars, bracelets and natural stone charged pieces. Striving for a eclectic take on accessories and accessorizing for an instant love affair!" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Dalliance Accessories" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/skin/frontend/default/blanco/images/dalliance-logo.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/skin/frontend/default/blanco/images/dalliance-screenshot.jpg">
```

Error I'm getting:

> Parser Mismatched Metadata: The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input
> metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple
> values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a
> given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the
> parsed result: 'og:image:url'

I dont get it. I've looked all over for answers, but no solutions have worked. There's no extra spaces at the end (one suggested solution) and I've hand type everything so theres no invisible characters either.

The problem seems to only come up with i put images in. So random. I had images just fine on the last version of the site. Anybody got any ideas?

**Update: So this is only a problem on the home page, and i still cant figure out why. I do not see this error anywhere else. (eg. When I debug http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/necklaces.html)**

Comment: Is it getting confused by the lack of closing slash on the og:image tag? I seem to remember FB being strict about syntax.

Comment: I know 2 image tags are allowed, however this was reported as a bug in the past (supposedly fixed). so, I thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: @GilBirman - i tried that already, but no luck. thank you anyway

Comment: I don't get an error when I put your link (`http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/`) in the debugger

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way around this. It's dirty, but it works.

**Background Info:** When i tried to change the website title for the home page, it told me 'you cannot change the title for this frozen page' etc. The 'frozen' part put up a mental red flag, but changing the title on the home page wasnt a big deal so I kept going.

Now, while trying to figure this out, I thought maybe it's looking for some of my old OG data because of whatever this 'frozen' data is. I assume for some reason I Cant change too much of my OG data on a page?

**The fix:** fter adding the 4 images that were previously specified in the last website version's OG data, it d allowed me to update the OG data via the debugger. It now reads completely fine. Adding the old image urls allowed me to update the title, description, etc. when people share.

My guess is there's some kind of check to see if too much data has changed and i somehow triggered it??? I'm not too sure why they would do that, but it seems to be the case.

Just to be clear, here is what all my image tags are now (the bottom 4 arent even valid urls, but they are what i used to have).

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/skin/frontend/default/blanco/images/dalliance-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/skin/frontend/default/blanco/images/dalliance-screenshot.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/wp-content/themes/Core/images/slider-miko.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/wp-content/themes/Core/images/slider-pagan.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/wp-content/themes/Core/images/slider-sugarchain-black.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dallianceaccessories.com/wp-content/themes/Core/images/og-logo.jpg" />
```

I will try to ween out these old image urls somehow or maybe populate the old urls with new images, until i can somehow find a proper way around this bug.